# How can I best prepare a nozzle for a gas cooktop so it doesn't lock into place?

Tags: pipe, gas, range

I have a Bosch cooktop, and several of the igniters have stopped working. I'd replace them, but the venturi nozzle that holds the burners in place has gotten completely frozen in place. This is the case with all 5 burners, and I just cannot get them out any more.

I've decided to replace the entire cooktop, but with the new one, what can I do to the pipe threads of the venturi nozzles to keep them from freezing in place? Is there a pipe thread lubricant I can apply that'll be resistant to the heat, and still work after years of operation?

Comment: You should not do anything to a new gas cooktop; you are more likely to do harm than help. There is high temp thread sealant to use on such threads. Try penetrating oil on the old nozzles and see if you can free them. Use the proper thread sealant and don't overtighten.

Comment: A good thorough cleaning and drying on  a regular basis so gunk does not sit on the parts your concerned with will minimize the chance for corrosion.

Comment: Since you've decided to replace the unit anyway you have nothing to lose by bringing a little more force to the table to learn just what it takes to break those frozen pieces free. Maybe you'll discover something that could extend the life of this unit (or the new one).

Answer (score 1):

High temp anti seize , auto parts stores carry this product type.
On the burner side of the gas valve there is no pressure so messing down stream of the valve is not a problem.
The stuff I use at work has copper in the name but it is a paste with the consistency of tooth paste doesn’t take much.  Just make sure it is high temp.